# Summarize methods to find the range of a function

Tags: analysis, functions

> Is the number of methods to find the *range* of a function are
>   limited? (so they can be put to notes/summary)

I may show 4 examples, the no.4 (using logical analysis) sometimes appear as auxiliary / additional reasoning for determining the $R_{f}$:

1. the function $$ f(x)= \frac{1+x}{1-x} $$ has $D_{f}= \mathbb{R}-\{1\}$. To find the *range* $R_{f}$ : Solve the **inequality** $$ y(1-x) = (1+x) \implies x = \frac{y-1}{1+y} \in D_{f} $$ to solve
   $$ \frac{y-1}{1+y} < 1 \: \:  \cup \: \: \frac{y-1}{1+y} > 1 $$
2. Same function as no.1, but by **Domain of the inverse** $$ x = \frac{y-1}{1+y} $$ but this is not enough for function such as $ f(x) = \sqrt{1-x} + \sqrt{1+x} $.
3. If the function is $$ y = f(x) = \sqrt{1-x} + \sqrt{1+x} $$, then by writing it to $$ A(y)x^{2} + B(y)x + C(y) = 0  $$ the $y$ must be such that $Discriminant(y) \ge 0$ and $A(y) \ne 0$. But sometimes this is also not enough, because in this particular case $y$ must be $y > 0$ and greater than $\sqrt{2}$ (by checking).
4. Use logical analysis. From no.3 above :

> But sometimes this is also not enough, because in this particular case
>   $y$ must be $y > 0$ and greater than $\sqrt{2}$ (by checking).

I would appreciate some summary on this basic Calculus idea. Also, the methods must be *elementary* (First year Calculus). Thanks before.

Comment: Sorry, but what are you asking?

Comment: "To find the *range* $R_{f}$ : Solve the **inequality** $$ y(1-x) = (1+x) \implies x = \frac{y-1}{1+y} \in D_{f} $$"

That's not an inequality, that's an equality. And what you found was not the range of $f$, you found the inverse. So, in short, what you wrote makes very little sense.

Comment: $x$ must be in the $D_{f}$, so to find the range of values of $y$, solve the inequality $x(y) \in D_{f}$.

Comment: @Arief That's not an inequality. And what in the world is $x(y)$?

Comment: @5xum to find all values of $y$ such that $x(y) \in D_{f}$, is as same as solving an inequality or inequalities. I have edited my post.

Comment: @5xum $x(y)$ is inverse function. By inequality he means if $x(y) \in D = (a, b)$ then $a < x(y) < b$.

Comment: @123 That assumes (1) that the inverse exists, and (2) that the domain is an interval.... Pretty strong assumptions...